# How to configure clients with two ldap servers : master and slave?

Tags: ldap, openldap, replication

I 've successfully managed to set up OPENLDAP replication :

**ldap1.mydomain.com**

**ldap2.mydomain.com**

(ldap2 initiates connection every 10min to ldap1.mydomain.com to synchronize)

What I want is that ldap1.mydomain.com is the default ldapserver for all clients (which is actually the case), but if it can't be reached, then ldap2.mydomain.com is used instead.

current ***/etc/ldap/ldap.conf*** (on all clients)

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=mydomain,dc=com
URI     ldap://ldap1.mydomain.com

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/My_Internal_CA.pem
TLS_REQCERT     demand
```

Where to put the "ldap2.mydomain.com" ? Is it right to do so ?

```
URI     ldap://ldap1.mydomain.com,ldap///ldap2.mydomain.com
```

Thank you in advance for your answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close but not quite. According to the `ldap.conf` man page, it should be:

```
URI ldap://ldap1.mydomain.com ldap://ldap2.mydomain.com
```

Just whitespace-separated, no quotes.

Comment: thank you ! i didn't know man command was working for conf files !